# How to find the date of the previous monday in C++

Tags: c++, date, c++-chrono

I want to make a program which takes no input and returns the date of the previous Monday. (I don't care about time zones. And I am only worried about Gregorian calendar). I am using [date by Howard Hinnant](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/tree/master/include/date). This is how I am doing it currently:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <date/date.h>

int main() {

    auto todays_day = date::year_month_weekday(date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()));

    auto todays_date = date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    int offset = 0;

    auto weekday = todays_day.weekday();

    if(weekday == date::Tuesday)
        offset = 1;
    else if (weekday == date::Wednesday)
        offset = 2;
    else if (weekday == date::Thursday)
        offset = 3;
    else if (weekday == date::Friday)
        offset = 4;
    else if (weekday == date::Saturday)
        offset = 5;
    else if (weekday == date::Sunday)
        offset = 6;

    auto lastMonday = date::year_month_day(todays_date - date::days(offset));

    std::cout << lastMonday;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this without [boost::previous_weekday](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html#idp173086288)? (It's not a requirement not to use boost. I am just wondering if it is possible)

Comment: For a date d represented by an integral type that increases by 1 each day, you can compute the offset by (d + a) % 7 where the constant a depends on your date scheme.

Comment: Whats 'a' @Bathsheba

Comment: It’s the constant (attainable by trial and error) that’s contingent on your date scheme.

Comment: Is there a wiki page explaining the formula with examples maybe? I have some questions? @Bathsheba

Comment: Just play with it. It will be obvious then.

Comment: Maybe I get it now. Jan 1, 1970 was thursday. The first monday of 1970 was 5th Jan. Therefore if I add 4 to the current date (assuming date is in integral type) and then modulus it with 7, I might get the offset in one statement @Bathsheba

Comment: @Hemil yes, and `4` would be the constant `a` that you're looking for. (Assuming that your date scheme starts at `1`, and also that the first day in it is `Jan 1, 1970`, of course)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key to understanding how to do this more simply is knowing this one fact about [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/tree/master/include/date):

`weekday` difference is circular (or modulo 7 if you prefer).  That is, any `weekday` subtracted from any `weekday` results in a number of `days` in the range [0, 6].  This effectively hides the underlying encoding of `weekday`.

Thus there is no need to translate [Monday, Sunday] into [0, 6] (or any other encoding):

```
#include "date/date.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto todays_date = date::floor<date::days>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
    date::year_month_day lastMonday = todays_date -
                                      (date::weekday{todays_date} - date::Monday);
    std::cout << lastMonday << '\n';
}
```

Instead you just have to decide how many days you need to subtract from a `sys_days` (`todays_date` in this example).  That number of days is today's `weekday` minus `Monday`.  If today is `Monday`, the result is `days{0}`.  If today is `Sunday`, the result is `days{6}`.  We could just as well be talking about finding the previous Friday.  The logic would not change.

Also, one can directly convert a `sys_days` to a `weekday`.  No need to go though `year_month_weekday`.

The code in the OP's question considers the "previous Monday" to be today if today happens to be a Monday.  And that is fine.  That is what is desired in many "previous weekday" algorithms.  And it is the logic I have coded above.

But it is also common to want the previous-weekday-algorithm to result in last week if the weekday you are seeking is today.  I.e. if today is Monday, compute a week ago instead of today.  That too is easily doable, and by pretty much the same algorithm.  One just has to subtract a day at the beginning of the algorithm if you desire this behavior:

```
auto todays_date = ...
todays_date -= date::days{1};
date::year_month_day lastMonday = ...
```

Comment: Is there a tag for the date library on stack overflow? If not is it logical to add one? I really appreciate your time

Comment: I'm not aware of a tag.  However [chrono] would not be a bad choice.  This library has been voted into the C++20 working draft as part of the `<chrono>` library.